# Why did my mongodb shut down due to memory errors and how do I prevent it?

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

```
sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2019-08-04 14:44:43 UTC; 1h 54min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2013 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 2013 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
root@mongodb-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc3-01:~#
```

I'm running mongodb on digitalocean using this preinstall: https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/mongodb

Why did the service stop? Isn't the service supposed to restart automatically on crash? How do I check if that's working.

Edit: Found journal

[image]

The logs:

```
2019-08-04T14:36:05.173+0000 I COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] command config.$cmd command: update { update: "system.sessions", ordered: false, allowImplicitCollectionCreation: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 }, $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:60 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3, w: 3 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } protocol:op_msg 102ms
2019-08-04T14:41:40.606+0000 E STORAGE  [conn4809] WiredTiger error (12) [1564929700:584465][2013:0x7f44d3d68700], file:collection-34-7943544189608520692.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __realloc_func, 133: memory allocation of 87330 bytes failed: Cannot allocate memory Raw: [1564929700:584465][2013:0x7f44d3d68700], file:collection-34-7943544189608520692.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __realloc_func, 133: memory allocation of 87330 bytes failed: Cannot allocate memory
2019-08-04T14:41:40.686+0000 F -        [conn4809] Invariant failure: seekRet resulted in status UnknownError: 12: Cannot allocate memory at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp 1911
2019-08-04T14:41:40.730+0000 F -        [conn4809] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2019-08-04T14:41:40.869+0000 F -        [conn4809] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 0x55be6af18cb1 0x55be6af17ec9 0x55be6af183ad 0x7f44e6eae890 0x7f44e6ae9e97 0x7f44e6aeb801 0x55be695573c8 0x55be6962eea5 0x55be69e36aeb 0x55be69de8216 0x55be69e0e39b 0x55be69e1fc2f 0x55be69e0e39b 0x55be69e1c6de 0x55be69e0e39b 0x55be69e10007 0x55be69e0e39b 0x55be69e03039 0x55be69e0e39b 0x55be69e5ee4d 0x55be69e5f7db 0x55be69becb95 0x55be6a988769 0x55be69603e9c 0x55be69605c29 0x55be69606b61 0x55be695f413a 0x55be695feeaa 0x55be695f9b77 0x55be695fd381 0x55be6a7b7a42 0x55be695f7d8f 0x55be695faf25 0x55be695f92b7 0x55be695f9bfd 0x55be695fd381 0x55be6a7b7fa5 0x55be6ae722e4 0x7f44e6ea36db 0x7f44e6bcc88f
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"23CDCB1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"23CCEC9"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"23CD3AD"},{"b":"7F44E6E9C000","o":"12890"},{"b":"7F44E6AAB000","o":"3EE97","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F44E6AAB000","o":"40801","s":"abort"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"A0C3C8","s":"_ZN5mongo24invariantOKFailedWithMsgEPKcRKNS_6StatusERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES1_j"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AE3EA5","s":"_ZN5mongo31WiredTigerRecordStoreCursorBase9seekExactERKNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12EBAEB","s":"_ZN5mongo16WorkingSetCommon5fetchEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10WorkingSetEmNS_11unowned_ptrINS_20SeekableRecordCursorEEE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"129D216","s":"_ZN5mongo10FetchStage6doWorkEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12C339B","s":"_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12D4C2F","s":"_ZN5mongo21SortKeyGeneratorStage6doWorkEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12C339B","s":"_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12D16DE","s":"_ZN5mongo9SortStage6doWorkEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12C339B","s":"_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12C5007","s":"_ZN5mongo15ProjectionStage6doWorkEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12C339B","s":"_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12B8039","s":"_ZN5mongo14MultiPlanStage6doWorkEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"12C339B","s":"_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"1313E4D","s":"_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor11getNextImplEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"13147DB","s":"_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"10A1B95"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"1E3D769","s":"_ZN5mongo12BasicCommand10Invocation3runEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_19CommandReplyBuilderE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AB8E9C"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"ABAC29"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"ABBB61","s":"_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointCommon13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageERKNS0_5HooksE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AA913A","s":"_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointMongod13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AB3EAA","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_processMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AAEB77","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AB2381"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"1C6CA42","s":"_ZN5mongo9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEENS0_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS0_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AACD8F","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardENS_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS2_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS0_9OwnershipE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AAFF25","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_sourceCallbackENS_6StatusE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AAE2B7","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine14_sourceMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AAEBFD","s":"_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"AB2381"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"1C6CFA5"},{"b":"55BE68B4B000","o":"23272E4"},{"b":"7F44E6E9C000","o":"76DB"},{"b":"7F44E6AAB000","o":"12188F","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.3", "gitVersion" : "7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.15.0-54-generic", "version" : "#58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55BE68B4B000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7F3B9CF97446F8FDDD1B41488C40342571A3243B" }, { "b" : "7FFFFAD01000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "02C5B0C16E57B3FCDB27AED1A50434F21797AEC7" }, { "b" : "7F44E83F0000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "20310A72634F3373FA7BCAB64DFB64CC204554B2" }, { "b" : "7F44E81D5000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "390E9CC4C215314B6D8ADE6D6E28F8518418039C" }, { "b" : "7F44E7D0A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4A1C995324942CDF5D843213896E6C7C0C9C67CC" }, { "b" : "7F44E7A7D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "439A262CC0127BA401707DEC7A28884D617550E0" }, { "b" : "7F44E7879000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "25AD56E902E23B490A9CCDB08A9744D89CB95BCC" }, { "b" : "7F44E7671000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9826FBDF57ED7D6965131074CB3C08B1009C1CD8" }, { "b" : "7F44E72D3000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A33761AB8FB485311B3C85BF4253099D7CABE653" }, { "b" : "7F44E70BB000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "41BDC55C07D5E5B1D8AB38E2C19B1F535855E084" }, { "b" : "7F44E6E9C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "28C6AADE70B2D40D1F0F3D0A1A0CAD1AB816448F" }, { "b" : "7F44E6AAB000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B417C0BA7CC5CF06D1D1BED6652CEDB9253C60D0" }, { "b" : "7F44E866F000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "64DF1B961228382FE18684249ED800AB1DCEAAD4" }, { "b" : "7F44E6886000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4F00E5207693FDC249DA42EC6472ACA6A7B929AE" }, { "b" : "7F44E6669000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BA5BF9A5C44F48C647E9D8270A5421AE81CCAD61" }, { "b" : "7F44E644D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69465D8AA6B19086ABF2455A703F9168BF82A69F" }, { "b" : "7F44E623F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CDAF1F1946846941F9D06414EC8C812D131A168E" }, { "b" : "7F44E5FF4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "00F419F64B0E70D8C5EEF7050369AA40B2A6E090" }, { "b" : "7F44E5DA2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E8A505FFF184C54BB6652424E44B852FBE27AACD" }, { "b" : "7F44E5B94000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "51B4F4B81488AADD19CC5817B9ABBB5B94BDE07F" }, { "b" : "7F44E5977000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EF3E006DFE3132A41D4D4DC0E407D6EA658E11C4" }, { "b" : "7F44E55F9000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0E2784298E7D3F4D894FE130ACEFA77C3E624F72" }, { "b" : "7F44E5294000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5AE5C31F804BE96532D0DB2091F19E472F2D4A0" }, { "b" : "7F44E5060000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "842BDF0B0EAAB82E19F1EABFC38769F4040FBE31" }, { "b" : "7F44E4E2A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C20D4B3BA13FCDCC3BF6857689BA9FC70BE3F6A5" }, { "b" : "7F44E4BA9000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D40EA9B5EC5BC46799E4A412319617BD38BE9341" }, { "b" : "7F44E48D3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69FBCF425EE6DF03DE93B82FBC2FC33790E68A96" }, { "b" : "7F44E46A1000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F400D5D643A7F9696DF0E6148FA99BEE6C1BDDF7" }, { "b" : "7F44E449D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C0CB7E35A4566A443F99DFBC1A54D3A0677C8A10" }, { "b" : "7F44E4292000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D78D71E8E016A534281B25B97CD7E5E9DB5FE00A" }, { "b" : "7F44E4077000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "ABB7E3F40302E6509DAD1F91DFB1F04B6A5FD072" }, { "b" : "7F44E3E36000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A1A98DB481968073636BBAECB561A3EA8ED198AE" }, { "b" : "7F44E3B07000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8DBD451EA5651283905E16FA7DFA9908688893A3" }, { "b" : "7F44E38F4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6036B89A3BB671B32E01464C0C82BFA016186352" }, { "b" : "7F44E36F0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F463E107B099910463BC32E837C73D341A52C27B" }, { "b" : "7F44E34E7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C2376C5B831991591F1A67B976758185F86896D8" }, { "b" : "7F44E325A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69BDEE5FA0FEEDF317308BE850F78761861D520A" }, { "b" : "7F44E2FB8000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "315D74995AAA32DE4D15BA25F335066988B1B230" }, { "b" : "7F44E2D82000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6673972A1C24A89EBAFBAE696188A4CB26C6DDEB" }, { "b" : "7F44E2B6C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "430827C33259C12248CF44B91A9A9821114376F5" }, { "b" : "7F44E2964000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3555B5F599C9787DFDDBF9E8DF6F706B9044D985" }, { "b" : "7F44E273B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "93A0931B1C2818F0EA224CE6FE5E31E84A9B55BB" }, { "b" : "7F44E252C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "669D4CCE42FA4382796EFFCF0C16F459F4382C4C" }, { "b" : "7F44E22E2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4B80C543356EE0AF9039EFE7C9EA1CC1F74C426A" }, { "b" : "7F44E1FD9000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BCE351987CF42B3D258B09F0CAC867758D935086" }, { "b" : "7F44E1DA1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "810686AF0D5FD350A4FB1CC4B5AFF44A05C102CB" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55be6af18cb1]
 mongod(+0x23CCEC9) [0x55be6af17ec9]
 mongod(+0x23CD3AD) [0x55be6af183ad]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f44e6eae890]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0xC7) [0x7f44e6ae9e97]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f44e6aeb801]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo24invariantOKFailedWithMsgEPKcRKNS_6StatusERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES1_j+0x0) [0x55be695573c8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo31WiredTigerRecordStoreCursorBase9seekExactERKNS_8RecordIdE+0x1C5) [0x55be6962eea5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16WorkingSetCommon5fetchEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_10WorkingSetEmNS_11unowned_ptrINS_20SeekableRecordCursorEEE+0xAB) [0x55be69e36aeb]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10FetchStage6doWorkEPm+0x106) [0x55be69de8216]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm+0x6B) [0x55be69e0e39b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo21SortKeyGeneratorStage6doWorkEPm+0x3F) [0x55be69e1fc2f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm+0x6B) [0x55be69e0e39b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9SortStage6doWorkEPm+0xFE) [0x55be69e1c6de]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm+0x6B) [0x55be69e0e39b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15ProjectionStage6doWorkEPm+0x47) [0x55be69e10007]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm+0x6B) [0x55be69e0e39b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14MultiPlanStage6doWorkEPm+0xB9) [0x55be69e03039]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9PlanStage4workEPm+0x6B) [0x55be69e0e39b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor11getNextImplEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x50D) [0x55be69e5ee4d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x4B) [0x55be69e5f7db]
 mongod(+0x10A1B95) [0x55be69becb95]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12BasicCommand10Invocation3runEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_19CommandReplyBuilderE+0xD9) [0x55be6a988769]
 mongod(+0xAB8E9C) [0x55be69603e9c]
 mongod(+0xABAC29) [0x55be69605c29]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointCommon13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageERKNS0_5HooksE+0x3C1) [0x55be69606b61]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo23ServiceEntryPointMongod13handleRequestEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7MessageE+0x3A) [0x55be695f413a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_processMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0xBA) [0x55be695feeaa]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0x97) [0x55be695f9b77]
 mongod(+0xAB2381) [0x55be695fd381]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEENS0_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS0_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameE+0x1A2) [0x55be6a7b7a42]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine22_scheduleNextWithGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardENS_9transport15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsENS2_23ServiceExecutorTaskNameENS0_9OwnershipE+0x15F) [0x55be695f7d8f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_sourceCallbackENS_6StatusE+0xAF5) [0x55be695faf25]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine14_sourceMessageENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0x357) [0x55be695f92b7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ServiceStateMachine15_runNextInGuardENS0_11ThreadGuardE+0x11D) [0x55be695f9bfd]
 mongod(+0xAB2381) [0x55be695fd381]
 mongod(+0x1C6CFA5) [0x55be6a7b7fa5]
 mongod(+0x23272E4) [0x55be6ae722e4]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76DB) [0x7f44e6ea36db]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x3F) [0x7f44e6bcc88f]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

The logs report some memory errors. How do I fix those and ensure they don't happen again?

Comment: Did the service even start at all? Where are the journal entries?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes I've been using the db for a few weeks. I'm not sure sure about the journal entries I'll try to look up what they are.

Comment: @MichaelHampton found journal edited the question with a screenshot, what do I do with it?

Comment: "Cannot allocate memory" seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your help, but it's not really obvious to me why it would say that. It's a 4gb server with only 1 user (me) in a test env. My mlab server is only 2gb but services dozens of connections with thousands of concurrent endusers. Don't really get it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about mongo version? Do you have updated version of mongo?